# Выявление новых сообщений в ВКонтакте на Raspberry PI

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, raspberry-pi

Пишу бота ВК для Raspberry PI. Идея проста. Как только появляется не прочитанное сообщение, зажигать диод (Для начала просто определить есть ли сообщения).

1. Кто делал нечто подобное, подскажите, как реализовать?
2. На чем лучше писать, на C++ или Python?
3. Как будет выглядеть проверка - бесконечный цикл (тогда много запросов к API контакта)? Или устанавливается соединение и мой клиент подпишется на обновления т.е. при появлении нового сообщения клиент будет оповещен (как приложение вк на андроиде например)?

Comment: Вот готовое решение для питона из примера библиотеки vk_api: https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/master/examples/longpoll.py

Comment: Лучше конечно python. У VK есть апи. У python есть библиотеки для VK. Тут разберешься как читать сообщения https://habrahabr.ru/post/319178/. Потом https://geektimes.ru/post/255050/ как зажигать диод

Comment: если это применимо к вашему случаю, то самый эффективный вариант при редких обновлениях это [Callback API](https://vk.com/dev/callback_api) -- ваш сервис сразу получает уведомление, когда интересные вам события происходят, не делая никаких периодических опросов.

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо!!! Все работает. Подскажите, а есть ли проверка, что все письма прочитаны? Хочу зажигать диод, когда есть не прочитанные сообщения и гасить, как только все сообщения прочитаются.

Comment: Все, нашел. Очень хорошая библиотека